# Reading RFID card using MFRC522

Tags: rfid

I am using MFRC522 Reader with STM32f030CC. I can read the serial number of the RFID card but after getting the serial number i am not able to select the tag and can't authentic the card.I am using the same library which is used in Arduino,Rasberry pi and STM32f4xx series with the required modification for STM32F030CC. And How can i read the remaining block of the RFID card after reading it's Serial Number?
Please suggest me some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is Solved . My Card Successfully Read.

*From Comments:*

We have changed our SPI Frequency setting by trail and error and we get working. Currently our settings are Crystal Frwq = 12MHz, and we get System clock = 32Mhz and HCLk = 32MHZ and after dividing HCLK/2 using APB1 Prescaler we get Peripheral clock = 16 MHZ. And our device is working.

Comment: How did you do it? im having a similar problem

Comment: We have changed our SPI Frequency setting by trail and error and we get working. Currently our settings are Crystal Frwq = 12MHz, and we get System clock = 32Mhz and HCLk = 32MHZ and after dividing HCLK/2 using APB1 Prescaler we get Peripheral clock = 16 MHZ. And our device is working.